# How to send a integer array via MPI_Send?

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

I'm trying to create a program in regular C that divides an integer array equally between any amount of process. For debugging purposes I'm using an integer array with 12 numbers and only 2 process so that the master process will have [1,2,3,4,5,6] and the slave1 will have [7,8,9,10,11,12]. However I'm getting an error saying: `MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer`.

After some research I found out that there is a function that does that (`MPI_Scatter`). Unfortunately, since I'm learning MPI the implementation is restricted to `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` only. Anyway, both `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` use a void*, and I'm sending a int* so it should work. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
int* create_sub_vec(int begin, int end, int* origin);
void print(int my_rank, int comm_sz, int n_over_p, int* sub_vec);

int main(void){

    int comm_sz;
    int my_rank;

    int vec[12] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int* sub_vec = NULL;
    int n_over_p;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);    

    n_over_p = 12/comm_sz;
    printf("Process %d calcula n_over_p = %d\n", my_rank, n_over_p);

    if (my_rank != 0) {
        MPI_Recv(sub_vec, n_over_p, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        print(my_rank, comm_sz, n_over_p, sub_vec);

    } else {

        printf("Distribuindo dados\n");
        for (int i = 1; i < comm_sz; i++) {
            sub_vec = create_sub_vec(i*n_over_p, (i*n_over_p)+n_over_p, vec);
            MPI_Send(sub_vec, n_over_p, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        printf("Fim da distribuicao de dados\n");

        sub_vec = create_sub_vec(0, n_over_p, vec);

        print(my_rank, comm_sz, n_over_p, sub_vec);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;

}

int* create_sub_vec(int begin, int end, int* origin){
    int* sub_vec;
    int size;
    int aux = 0;
    size = end - begin;
    sub_vec = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
        *(sub_vec+aux) = *(origin+i);
        aux += 1;
    }
    return  sub_vec;
}

void print(int my_rank, int comm_sz, int n_over_p, int* sub_vec){
    printf("Process %d out of %d received sub_vecotr: [ ", my_rank, comm_sz);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_over_p; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d, ", *(sub_vec+i));
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement parallel sorting?

Comment: No, it is a simple exercice to sum the elements of a vector in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `sub_vec` is not allocated on non zero rank.
It is up to you to do that (e.g. MPI does not allocate the receive buffer).

the receive part should look like

```
if (my_rank != 0) {
    sub_vec = (int *)malloc(n_over_p * sizeof(int));    
    MPI_Recv(sub_vec, n_over_p, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
```

As you wrote, the natural way is via `MPI_Scatter()` (and once again, it is up to you to allocate the receive buffer before starting the scatter.